# Restoring Windows XP from grub

Tags: grub, dual-boot, reboot

Previously I had a dual boot with Windows XP and Fedora. I have deleted Fedora and extended the C drive using Mini Tool Partition Wizard. Then I restarted the system with the Windows XP bootable CD. The CD is not detected and  the following is displayed:

```
GNU GRUB version 0.97 (637K lower/513920K upper memory)
[Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.For the first word,
TAB lists possible command completions.Anywhere else 
TAB lists the possible completions of a device/filename]

grub>
```

Please help me to restore Windows XP.

Comment: This is unusual, did you change the boot priority for your CD Drive in your BIOS settings?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you no longer have the Windows MBR.  When a computer boots up it needs to read Sector 0, Position 0, that is where grub or the MBR is installed. When you removed Fedora, you removed the menu.lst file that grub needs in order to understand where the other bootable items are located.  In order to get back into Windows again, you needed to restore the Windows MBR before you deleted Fedora. If you can get your XP CD to boot (which you may need to change the boot order in your BIOS) you can follow the instructions here: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/repairmbr.htm

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.techzonez.com/forums/showthread.php/3975-Fix-the-MBR-in-Windows-XP):

Use the [Windows XP recovery console](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307654) to reinstall Windows' MBR and boot loader (boot from the CD, press R when prompted and then run `FIXMBR` and `FIXBOOT`).

Answer (score 0):

If you just extended the disk and the software didn't crash the MBR of the windows partition, you could try:

```
> root (hdX,Y)  
> makeactive     # activate NTFS partition
> chainloader +1 # boot
> boot
```